# Gradle: add dependency to github project to dev branch instead of master

Tags: git, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to get "dev" branch instead of "master" branch from PhotoView project in Github:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/tree/dev

But by default the dependencies get "master" branch.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
}
```

How should I change this dependency to get "dev" branch instead of "master"?

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:dev-SNAPSHOT'
```

source https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io

Answer (score 2):

It can be a general consideration.

> `compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'`

It downloads the aar from Central Maven, not from github.

If you would like to work with the dev branch and gradle, you should ask the author for a snapshot release, or you have to build it locally.

BTW, about this lib, the version 1.2.3 is very recent. Why do you want to work with the dev branch?

Comment: You are right when say that version 1.2.3 is very recent, but there are some bugs solved in the dev branch which affect to my app (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/pull/177, https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/123). In addition, I know the aar comes from Central Maven, but with Gradle exits plugins for manage git dependencies, for example: https://github.com/bat-cha/gradle-plugin-git-dependencies , but I have not gotten to do it work yet with an android app

Comment: It clones the repo locally.

Comment: Ok I have it locally, now, how should I change the dependency for get the new version in this local repository?

Comment: the dependency is local (:myLocalLib). To update the code, you have to use git.